# How to add signers with dynamic signtab and Texg tab in DocuSign template with api

Tags: templates, docusignapi

In my application, I have multiple signers dynamic from database and each of them has to sign a DocuSign agreement. I have a DocuSign template and how  to add signers dynamically from database with dynamically create signtab, Tex tab for each signers in DocuSign template with api.
how can I use create envelope with signers and tabs on fly?
how to set the signheretab position at the exact position so that each signer can sign one after other?
how to add label like **name**: 'testname'  **signature** :   **date**: in template dynamically with API?

Comment: How to add tabs here on fly???
'templateId'     =>’templateid,
'emailSubject'   => Agreement', 
  'status'         => 'sent',                                               
 'templateRoles'  => [ [
            'name'     => ‘first name’,
            'email'    => ‘first email’,                                                    
             'roleName' => 'buyer',
             'routingOrder' => '1',
              'clientUserId'  => ‘clientuserid’, 
               'tabs' =>[ 
                        'textTabs' => 
 ]
]]

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use [composite templates](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/templates/composite/). That would give you more flexibility and ability to make more complex scenarios in the future.

Here is an [example of JSON for a composite templates](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-composite-template-embedded/) that includes additional tabs:

```
{
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "compositeTemplateId": "1",
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "recipients": {
                        "carbonCopies": [
                            {
                                "email": "'"${CC_EMAIL}"'",
                                "name": "'"${CC_NAME}"'",
                                "recipientId": "2",
                                "roleName": "cc"
                            }
                        ],
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "clientUserId": "1000",
                                "email": "'"${SIGNER_EMAIL}"'",
                                "name": "'"${SIGNER_NAME}"'",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "roleName": "signer"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "sequence": "2"
                }
            ],
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "' > $request_data
                    printf "${template_id}" >> $request_data
                    printf '"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "compositeTemplateId": "2",
            "document": {
                "documentBase64": "' >> $request_data
                cat $doc1_base64 >> $request_data
                printf '",
                "documentId": "1",
                "fileExtension": "html",
                "name": "Appendix 1--Sales order"
            },
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "recipients": {
                        "carbonCopies": [
                            {
                                "email": "'${CC_EMAIL}'",
                                "name": "'"${CC_NAME}"'",
                                "recipientId": "2",
                                "roleName": "cc"
                            }
                        ],
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "'"${SIGNER_EMAIL}"'",
                                "name": "'"${SIGNER_NAME}"'",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "roleName": "signer",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "signHereTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "anchorString": "**signature_1**",
                                            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                                            "anchorXOffset": "20",
                                            "anchorYOffset": "10"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "sequence": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```